# What is area using a double integrals between the curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, analysis

What is area enclosed between  curve/coordinate axes?

$$(\frac{x}{a})^3+(\frac{y}{b})^3=\;(\frac{x}{h})^2+(\frac{y}{k})^2\;,(x=0,y=0); $$

$ (a,b,h,k)$ are constants. And  $ x,y \geq 0$

Comment: Add always your attempt with your question in order to get usefull answers.

Comment: thanks, its all right @Narasimham

Comment: I dont understand why u do this , is the same question? @Narasimham

Comment: That is alright now..you get axes intercepts $ a^3/h^2, b^3/k^2$ now easy

Comment: thanks, I think is necessary a change of variables. @Narasimham

Comment: Pl see my above last comment..

Comment: I only one case i think $x,y\geq 0$ and $(\frac{x}{a})^3+(\frac{y}{b})^3=\;(\frac{x}{h})^2+(\frac{y}{k})^2$

Comment: yes!,  I see your comment now @Narasimham

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to calculate the area for each curve separately instead then the area you want is the difference of the two

---

In terms of $\left(\frac xh\right)^2+\left(\frac yk\right)^2=1,\{x,y>0\}$
if we say: $$x_1=x/h,y_1=y/k\Rightarrow dxdy=hkdx_1dy_1$$
now what remains is the integral of a circle multiplied by $hk$ which is $\frac{hk\pi}{4}$

---

For the $\left(\frac xa\right)^3+\left(\frac yb\right)^3=1,\{x,y>0\}$ we can do a similar thing and get:
$$x_2^3+y_2^3=1,dxdy=abdx_2dy_2$$
and we need to calculate:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{1-x_2^3}} abdy_2dx_2=ab\int_0^1\sqrt[3]{1-x_2^3}dx_2$$
And i believe this integral can only be represented in terms of the beta function.

---

Overall your answer should be:
$$\left|\frac{hk\pi}{4}-\frac{ab}{3}B\left(\frac 13,\frac 43\right)|\right|$$

Comment: if $x,y>0$ then the intersections are not within this region necessarily